# How to show a message box from edit/add new button click of a devexpress gridview

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a devexpress nested gridview. Both the master and detail gridviews have link buttons for edit and add new activities. After either inserting new row or updating an existing row, I have to show a message box saying "Your update has been saved successfully". This could be a simple javascript alert box or a message displayed on the page itself. Both the gridviews use objectdatasource. I tried the following codes in the RowUpdated event of both the gridview and the objectdatasource:

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("alert(Your updated has been saved successfully')");

or

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + Your updated has been saved successfully+ "');", true);

But in either case, no message box is displayed. If I used the same code in the button click event of a button on the page, then it works fine. I event tried to set the text value of a asp:Literal control. It also didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle [ASPxGridView.RowInserted](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowInsertedtopic) and [ASPxGridView.RowUpdated](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowUpdatedtopic) grid events to set custom property containing message into [ASPxGridView.JSProperties](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_JSPropertiestopic).
Then handle client side [ASPxClientGridView.EndCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_EndCallbacktopic) event to check if custom property exists and raise alert.

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Exception == null) {
        ((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpUpdatedMessage"] = "Your update has been saved successfully";
    }
}
```

```
<dx:aspxgridview ID="ASPxGridView1" ... onrowupdated="ASPxGridView1_RowUpdated">
    <clientsideevents
        EndCallback="function(s, e) {
                        if (s.cpUpdatedMessage) {
                            alert(s.cpUpdatedMessage);
                            delete s.cpUpdatedMessage;
                        }
                    }"
    />
```

Do the same for RowInserted event. 
There is similar [example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2379.aspx) in DevEx support center.

Alternatively, you can [use solution with e.command](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S134916.aspx) parameter.

Comment: This works fine for the master gridview. Thank you so much for directing me in the right direction. Now I want to show a message either through an alert box or a message through a web control such as label or literal control.