# Client side event that fires after ASPxClientGridView.ApplyFilter performs its work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress, client-side

This link explains how to handle it on the server side via the ASPxGridView.AfterPerformCallback event:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q274366.aspx

How can I handle it on the client side?

I am working on a custom server control and I have this client side function on my control:

```
    applyFilterToGridView: function () {
        this.theGridView.ApplyFilter(this.filterCondition); 
        this.filterAppliedEvent();
    }
```

Because ApplyFilter does a callback, this.filterAppliedEvent() is not called at the right time which should be after the filtering is complete. this.filterAppliedEvent() is a client side function.

This event is fired after the filter is applied:

```
protected void theGridView_AfterPerformCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewAfterPerformCallbackEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CallbackName == "APPLYFILTER")
            {
            }
        }
```

Is there some way to to tell the client to call filterAppliedEvent from the AfterPerformCallback event?

I would prefer to be able to run this.filterAppliedEvent() after AfterPerformCallback on the client side if possible.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT ( Solution thanks to Filip ):**

C#:

```
  protected void theGridView_AfterPerformCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewAfterPerformCallbackEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CallbackName == "APPLYFILTER")
            {
                ASPxGridView gv = sender as ASPxGridView;
                gv.JSProperties["cp_FilterApplied"] = "true";
                gv.JSProperties["cp_VisibleRowCount"] = gv.VisibleRowCount;
            }
        }

theGridView.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "function(s,e){"theGridView.theGridView_OnEndCallback(s, e);}";
```

JS:

```
theGridView_OnEndCallback: function (s, e) {
    if (s.cp_FilterApplied) {
        if (s.cp_FilterApplied.indexOf('true') != -1) {
            this.adjustGridViewSize();/*Uses visible row count.*/
            delete s.cp_FilterApplied;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In `theGridView_AfterPerformCallback` add entry to `JSProperties` collection, e.g. `cp_FilterApplied`.
2. Add `EndCallback` client side event handler.
3. In `EndCallback` handler execute `this.filterAppliedEvent()` if `cp_FilterApplied` exists.
4. Delete that property so that subsequent callback doesn't execute `filterAppliedEvent` method.

Look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743294/how-to-show-a-message-box-from-edit-add-new-button-click-of-a-devexpress-gridvie/9748367#9748367) for code example. 
It's really the same problem, just set js property in `theGridView_AfterPerformCallback` instead of `ASPxGridView1_RowUpdated` and adjust names/js code to your needs.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! I will update my question with the solution code.

Comment: you guys rock! For some reason, ClientEnabled property needs to be set to true from clientside atleast once per postback, for it to work correctly. It's kinda weird, but I ended up using JSProperties to set ClientEnabled = true in my code!