# The ScriptManager alert does not show even when having a ScriptManage control in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a Devexpress GridView `gv` in my aspx page to show and manage all accounts.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gv" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
        GridLines="None"  
        AllowPaging="true"  
        CssClass="mGrid" > 
        <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectByRowClick="True" AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="True"/>
     <Styles>
          <Header BackColor="#4FC9C4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></Header>
      </Styles>

</dx:ASPxGridView>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Each row of Gridview has a Command Button `Delete` allowing adminnistrator to delete any account except  `Admin` account.

Take a look at the code behind:

```
  protected void grid_InitDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
    {
                //...get username value from e
                if(username=="Admin")
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    gv.CancelEdit();
                    string script = "alert('Cannot delete Admin account');";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", script, true);
                    return;
                } 
               else 
                 {
                     ...delete account
                 }

     }
```

When I built this page and clicked on button Delete in Admin account--> no Alert show as I expected.

Try to debug, program hits all lines inside `if` statement (include  `string script = "alert('Cannot delete Admin account');";`) and then do `return`

I really dont know why the Alert does not show there???

Help!!!

Comment: did you try to debug it inside devtools ?

Comment: @Tigran this grid_InitDeleting above is the delete default function of Devexpress GridView, then it will be called in function LoadGridView by : gv.RowDeleting += grid_InitDeleting;

Comment: I mean debug inside *browser dev tools*, debug javascript actually and see if code actually reached by the program.

Comment: Delete initiates callback and you should use EndCallback handler to execute js code after callback finishes. Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748730/cannot-call-a-js-function-from-code-behind) and questions referenced in answer.

Comment: @Filip thank you, I got the solution in your recommending-answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the **ASPxGridView.EnableCallBacks** property to **False**.

See:

- [The Concept of Callbacks](https://www.devexpress.com/issue=K18387)
- [MS Update Panel](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/MSAjax/UpdatePanel.aspx)

for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you setting SettingsBehavior-ConfirmDelete to true and SettingsText-ConfirmDelete=.
Then handle OnRowDeleting Event like this [Example Row Deleting](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E131)

Can set property via jsproperties ([jsproperties](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_JSPropertiestopic)) and Handle EndCallback Event to show alert.